# retrieving Strings from database into an ArrayList then using it to enable specific items in JMenuBar

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

This is my Code :

```
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        try {
            con = new DBConnect().getConnection();
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM m_auth WHERE USERGROUP = '"+txtUSERGROUP.getText()+"' order by NO asc";
            st = con.createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

            while(rs.next()) {
                List.add(rs.getString("AuthCode"));
                System.out.println(List);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, e);
        }        
    }
```

let say the Usergroup is "Admin" and once the code above finished, these are the item that are stored inside the ArrayList :

```
[F01]
[F0101]
[F0102]
[P01]
[P0101]
[P010101]
[P010102]
[P0102]
```

what I need to figure out next, is how I can use the items in the ArrayList to enable some menu in menuBar which has its name stored in the ArrayList, something like this :

```
//read all the Item in the ArrayList, then use the List items to set the referenced menu name to be enabled 

F01.setEnabled(true);
F0101.setEnabled(true);
F0102.setEnabled(true);
P01.setEnabled(true);
P0101.setEnabled(true);
P010101.setEnabled(true);
P010102.setEnabled(true);
P0102.setEnabled(true);
```

Comment: `if(auth == admin)` you probably want `if(auth.equals(admin))`

Comment: This: `while(rs.next()) {
            ArrayList List = new ArrayList();                
            List.add(rs.getString("AuthCode"));        }` keeps creating and discarding ArrayLists within the while loop, something I'd call "futile code" since it does nothing of useful purpose. If you want to fill an ArrayList, you need to declare and initialize the variable *before* the loop, and fill it within the loop.

Comment: @dustytrash sorry for the typo, I mean I need something more flexible than the last pieceof code I posted, anyway it just a quick example.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels , yea, I usually do that, but since this is my first post and I was kinda mistyped here and there, just trying to explain my intention in a quick way.

Comment: And you're still creating an ArrayList object **within** the loop. Please follow our advice and stop doing this. Create your ArrayList in a place that makes sense, since by creating it in the loop, you're throwing data that shouldn't be discarded. Also please create and post a valid [mcve], code we can run and test. Please read the link.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels , done

Answer (score 1):

You should declare that `List` variable outside of the loop. Otherwise you're just creating it & discarding it after every iteration.

```
// Consider doing this whole method once. Somewhere else
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try {
        con = new DBConnect().getConnection();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM m_auth order by no asc";
        st = con.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
        // listOfAuthCodes could also be a class variable
        ArrayList<String> listOfAuthCodes = new ArrayList<String>();

        while(rs.next()) {                
            listOfAuthCodes .add(rs.getString("AuthCode"));
        }
        // You can now have a list of AuthCode's from the db
        // 'userHasAdminAuthCode ' should be a class variable to use in another method
        userHasAdminAuthCode = doesAdminAuthCodeExistInTheDatabase(listOfAuthCodes);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, e);
    }        
}

private boolean doesAdminAuthCodeExistInTheDatabase(List<String> authCodesFromDatabase)
{
    for(String s : authCodesFromDatabase)
    {
        if(s.equals("Admin"))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    if(this.userHasAdminAuthCode) {
        adminLogin();
    }
    else {
        staffLogin();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know that, I am sorry if I got it wrong, I was just trying to do it a lil bit quick, I hope I could still show the real problem I am facing and trying to resolve.

I am okay with the part of retrieving the data into the Arraylist, now I just need to know how to use the ArrayList to enable specific items in the MenuBar as referenced by the ArrayList items.

Comment: The ArrayList gets every row though. Do you want to reference all rows, or just 1 row relating to the user?

Comment: @DaveTran: if this is not the "real" problem, then you've just wasted my time and dusty trash's with a red herring. Please fix your question so that it shows us a valid representation of your problem and your real code, best if a [mcve].

Comment: @dustytrash , Yes I wan to reference all rows, because the rows retrieved from the user's data containing only all the item he has access to, so all the item in the rows must be enabled.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels
I think I have mentioned in the post, the bottomline is

I have an ArrayList which I have successfully retrieved the item from database, and yes I have declared the List outside of the loop, 

Now I just need to knwo how to use the List to enable the referenced item in the Menu Bar. Thank you.

Comment: @DaveTran I agree with Hovercraft Full Of Eels. But I gave it one last try anyways. Take a look at my edits if that's what you meant

Comment: I am sorry, I am a lil bit slow but I am fixing it now,

Comment: @DaveTran Why does the application get every row from the database? Why don't you just `SELECT * WHERE userName = nameOfTheUserUsingTheApplication`?

Comment: @dustytrash yes I have that coding written on the other form, I forgot to put the Where clause, I was thinking that maybe an unspecific case would be enough as an example, when I got the solution I needed, I will be implementing it in the program that I wrote, and I will post the whole code here.